# CoreData - how to keep the object up-to-date in a different thread/context?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data, magicalrecord

I have an application that has 2 `ManagedObject`s: `Article` and `List`. There's a many-to-many relation between them (an Article can be on multiple lists; the list can contain multiple articles).

In the UI for the article I have a `+` button that displays (in a popover controller) the list of `Lists` and allows for adding or removing of the article from them.

So in the `ArticleViewController` I keep an instance of the Article object as a property: `self.article`.

```
ListsTableViewController *contentViewController = [[ListsTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
contentViewController.selectionBlock = ^(BOOL wasSelected, List *list) {
    NSLog(@"%@ was%@ selected?", list, wasSelected ? @"" : @" not");
    if (wasSelected) {
        [self.article addToList:list];
    } else {
        [self.article removeFromList:list];
    }
};

self.myPopoverController = [[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController];
contentViewController.selectedLists = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[self.article.lists allObjects] valueForKeyPath:@"objectID.URIRepresentation"]];
[contentViewController viewDidAppear:YES];
[self.myPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender
                                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                                 animated:YES];
```

I pass the list of `objectID.URIRepresentation`s of the lists to the `contentViewController` that allows me to initially show the checkmarks at the lists that were originally selected.

The `addToList:` and `removeFromList:` methods of the `Article` object look like this (I'm using `MagicalRecord` in my project):

```
- (void) addToList:(List *)list
{
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        List *l = [list MR_inContext:localContext];
        Article *n = [self MR_inContext:localContext];

        NSMutableSet *s = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:n.lists];
        [s addObject:l];
        n.lists = s;
        s = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:l.articles];
        [s addObject:n];
        l.articles = s;
    } completion:nil
  ];
}
```

When I first enter the `ArticleViewController` and tap the `+` button, it properly shows me the lists that the article is in. However when I do some adding/removing from lists there, close the popup view controller and open it again, it seems like the `self.article` doesn't have the updated lists set (they seem to be added in a different thread/context and not propagated to this one?). I see the lists that were there the first time.

Going out of the `ArticleViewController` and coming back fixes the problem (forces re-read) but then after the first add the problem is still there.

How to *invalidate* the `Lists` set in the `Article` to force re-fetching the relationship when accessed?

Comment: Why are you doing `NSMutableSet *s = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:n.lists];` ? Why aren't you using the KVC accessor for the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of trial-and-error I found a working solution (at least working for now). I'm not sure how **smart** it is though:

```
- (void) addToList:(List *)list
{
    __block NSSet *set;
    NSManagedObjectContext *c = self.managedObjectContext;
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        List *l = [list MR_inContext:localContext];
        Article *n = [self MR_inContext:localContext];

        NSMutableSet *s = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:n.lists];
        [s addObject:l];
        n.lists = s;
        set = n.lists;
    } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        NSMutableSet *set2 = [NSMutableSet set];
        for (List *l in [set allObjects]) {
            [set2 addObject:[l MR_inContext:c]];
        }
        self.lists = set2;
    }];
}
- (void) removeFromList:(List *)list
{
    __block NSSet *set;
    NSManagedObjectContext *c = self.managedObjectContext;
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        List *l = [list MR_inContext:localContext];
        Article *n = [self MR_inContext:localContext];

        NSMutableSet *s = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:n.lists];
        [s removeObject:l];
        n.lists = s;
        set = n.lists;
    } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        NSMutableSet *set2 = [NSMutableSet set];
        for (List *l in [set allObjects]) {
            [set2 addObject:[l MR_inContext:c]];
        }
        self.lists = set2;
    }];
}
```